how to calculate summation of a polynomial up to say n = 10 in WolframAlpha
I want to calculate the following summation up to n=10.
Figure 1
I know one way is to get the simplified expression but in many cases they may not be available. Is there another way to do it in wolframalpha?
Figure 2
I tried to use
n=4; before the summation

Is this what you are looking for?
Sum[k!,{k,2,4}]

which instantly returns 32
or
Sum[k!,{k,2,10}]

which instantly returns 4037912
WolframAlpha isn't really a "programming language" where you give it a sequence of statements and expect it to do those one step at a time and assign values to variables and later use those variables to remember the values assigned to calculate results. Instead you give WolframAlpha a single expression and it displays the result of evaluating that single expression.
